# Is there a functional difference between black and white Wii remotes?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers

I know that this is a silly question, but is there any difference between black and white Wii controllers apart from the color?

At shops and on online shops, the black one is 10 Euro more expensive than the white one!

Is there any difference or just the black is cool?

Comment: Really?  I'd look at a different online retailer or go to a store.  They should be the same price regardless of color (assuming you're comparing the regular and "plus" controllers).

Comment: Black is just cool, for examples of different colours costing significantly different prices see Apple's products, pretty much any time over the past decade.

Comment: In terms of functionality, I have found the white is easier to find in the dark. :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference except for the colour.

I'm not familiar with the actual prices, but one thing to pay attention to is whether or not you're looking at a normal Wii Remote or the Wii Remote Plus that includes the MotionPlus sensor. If that's not it, then the price difference you're seeing is simply due to the "novelty" of the black controller.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference. It's the same thing except one is black and the other one is white. The black Wiimote is newer than the white one. Other than that, it's the same thing.